# TortoiseHg pointing to an old version

Tags: 16.04, mercurial

I installed Mercurial and TortoiseHG on my Ubuntu16.04 VM.

Running `hg version` shows me that the version is `3.7.3`.

Running `sudo apt-get install tortoisehg` shows that the TortoiseHg is already the newest version `3.7.3-1`.

However, when I run `thg` I get this:

```
    #!python
    ** Mercurial version (3.7.3).  TortoiseHg version (2.10)
    ** Command: 
    ** CWD: /home/rp
    ** Encoding: UTF-8
    ** Extensions loaded: 
    ** Python version: 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
    ** System: Linux rp-VM 4.15.0-29-generic #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 18 08:54:04 UTC 2018 x86_64
    ** Qt-4.8.7 PyQt-4.11.4 QScintilla-2.9.1


    This version of TortoiseHg requires Mercurial version 2.7.n to 2.8.n, but found 3.7.3
```

Is there any way to make the `thg` command target the latest TortoiseHg version?
Or do I need to remove something?

EDIT:

Output of `type thg`: `thg is /usr/local/bin/thg`

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to include the output of `type thg`. You must have two versions of TortoiseHg installed.

Comment: @Melebius The output is: `thg is /usr/local/bin/thg`. I assumed that there are 2 versions installed but I don't know how to address/specify either one (for usage or deletion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `thg` binary executed by default is installed in `/usr/local/bin`. This location is not managed by APT, so it wasn’t most likely installed by APT (or it has been moved/copied from the default location).

To **uninstall** it, just remove the file `/usr/local/bin/thg` (you’ll need `sudo` for that).

You can also keep using both versions but you must provide the full path when launching the non-default version. The [version installed by APT](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/tortoisehg/filelist) should be located at `/usr/bin/thg`.

If you suspect there are even more `thg` versions in your system, you can find them all using the command:

```
find / -name thg
```